# The preferred way of installing and using global npm packages?

Tags: node.js, npm

To install a package globally, one has to use `sudo`, but then again npm does not recommend using `sudo`. So the official recommendation is [this](https://docs.npmjs.com/getting-started/fixing-npm-permissions#option-two-change-npms-default-directory). I followed all the steps from 1 to 5 in Option 2. But when I want to use an NPM package from terminal, I have to define the full path. For instance I installed [npm-check-updates](https://www.npmjs.com/package/npm-check-updates), but I can't run `ncu` or `npm-check-updates` command from terminal, because it says `bash: ncu: command not found`. I have to type the full path like this: `~/.npm-global/bin/ncu`.

How do I fix this?

Comment: obvious question here: did you put the relevant path export in the correct shell profile? if using zsh you'd chuck it in your .zshrc file for example.

Comment: Try to use NVM that also best way https://github.com/creationix/nvm

Comment: @Remi If you are referring to the step 4 and 5 described [here](https://docs.npmjs.com/getting-started/fixing-npm-permissions#option-two-change-npms-default-directory) yes I have done that

Comment: @NiroshanRanapathi Thanks but I am not really inclined to increase package overhead by installing one more package to support the current package. Yes NVM is a very popular one and I might consider it as a last resort, but for now I would like to see some other ways to handle the situation...

Comment: obvious second question: did you reload your shell?

Comment: @Remi I did....

Comment: I have the same problem, how did you fix yours?

Answer (score 1):

Hi there I noticed this hasn't been answered so I'm responding just in case I or anybody else runs into the same problem in future.

Here's what worked for me:

```
npm install -g npm-check-updates

ncu -u
```

after running the second command, you should see a list of all your dependencies and their latest versions then run

```
npm install
```

to install new versions.